# How do I create custom form submit in product detail

Tags: forms

Im writing a project and i have to create a field in product detail to get number .
Like this

[image]

To do this , i refer to product.info.extrahint and put my block inside .
But when i click submit button , it alway refer to add cart page even if action form are whatever . Im confusing . Any idea to help me out ? . Thank in advance

Comment: I would assume, this block is inside the add-to-cart form.

Comment: Thank you for reply , Fabian . Do you have any advice for this case ?

Comment: Either put YOUR form outside the magento core form or use JS to collect the data and send it via js

Answer (score 2):

Youre problem is that you have a form inside a form.

check catalog/product/view.phtml
~ line 42:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
```

~ line 104:

```
</form>
```

Somewhere in between you are loading the extra form with the product.info.extrahint block

Comment: Thank you . But i still want to do that . What should i do ?

Comment: Nested forms are not valid HTML. You should find another way.

Answer (score 1):

If you put your form in view.phtml it will trigger add to cart button. You need to move block out from the form.

Answer (score 0):

Done . I used java script and set onclick attribute for my button to pass product form .

Thank all